# How to print the value without a decimal in jrxml

Tags: jasper-reports

I have added the new parameter with a class BigDecimal.But I need to print the value without a decimal in PDF.Please suggest me how I need to print the value without a decimal.

```
 <parameter name="ESRTotal" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
 <textField>
            <reportElement x="37" y="142" width="105" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format($P{ESRTotal})]]></textFieldExpression>
         </textField>
```

Comment: I need to print as 74.75 and also 74(space)75 but I can print only as 74.75 only.I could not print as 74 75.Please help me it is very important for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding whitespace to a number is not supported by DecimalFormat as it's not considered a valid format for a number.

If you really do need this, you could consider taking the String representation of the format and then replacing the decimal point with a space.

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format($P{ESRTotal})).toString().replace('.', ' ')]]></textFieldExpression>
```